# How to fit custom curves for each level of facet_wrap in ggplot2 R?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, curve-fitting

I have a scatterplot with x = xaxis and y = yaxis and two levels that I need to split and analyze the data separately with. For each set of data, I need to plot a custom function of the form `y ~ (A*((B*x/C)-1) - 1)*log(x))`. For each of the levels, I need to specify the A, B, and C. How do I do this in ggplot2?

A sample code of ggplot2. I have generated random data, so the smooth function may not make sense for this data (but does for my original data)

```
xaxis = c(1:100)
yaxis = rnorm(100,2,0.1)
level = rep(c("A","B"), 50)

    
df <- data.frame(xaxis, yaxis, level)
ggplot(df,aes(x= xaxis, y = yaxis, col = level)) + geom_point() +facet_wrap(.~level, scales="free")+ geom_smooth(method="lm", formula = y ~ (A*((B*x/C)-1) - 1)*log(x))
```

Comment: The purpose of `ggplot` is visualization. It has some functionality for standard models, but when modeling gets complicated it's usually easier to do your modeling separate from your visualizing. I'd suggest fitting your models using `nls` (or whatever function you prefer), and then plotting the results, rather than putting a lot of effort into making both happen at once..

Comment: What's `level`? it's not defined and it doesn't exist in the dataframe

Comment: @GregorThomas I make the same point all the time, though in this case it would be pretty easy to run `nls` inside `geom_smooth`. The bigger problem here is that I don't think this model as specified would ever converge. It contains a B and C which are actually just forming a ratio. Their individual values aren't decidable by regression.

Comment: @Mouad_Seridi Oops I have added it now

Comment: @Biotechgeek do you just want to draw the lines `y ~ (A*((B*x/C)-1) - 1)*log(x)` where you specify A, B and C, or do you want to find A, B and C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If are a trying to fit a model to find the values of A, B and C using your formula, you can't, for the simple reason that B and C only appear as a ratio in your formula. So if the true value of "B" was 4 and the true value of "C" was 2, then this would be indistinguishable from, say, a "B" of 12  and a "C" of 6. Only the ratio of the two can be estimated by regression.

If you just want to plot the *lines* specified by your formula, where you pre-specify A, B and C, then that *is* possible. For example:

```r
my_func <- function(x, A, B, C) (A*((B*x/C)-1) - 1)*log(x)

ggplot(df,aes(x= xaxis, y = yaxis, col = level)) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(.~level, scales = "free")+ 
  geom_function(data = data.frame(xaxis = 0, yaxis = 0, level = "A"),
                fun = my_func,
                args = list(A = 0.05, B = 2, C = 5)) +
  geom_function(data = data.frame(xaxis = 0, yaxis = 0, level = "B"),
                fun = my_func,
                args = list(A = 0.1, B = -0.0005, C = 1))
```

[image]